# How do I use Leaflet with Mapbox template?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I am using the Mapbox template: DC Properties
I am calling 3 tiles, including the base tile.

I have another tile of markers, but I would like to change this to Leaflet dataset and clustering.

Having trouble integrating the Leaflet map and marker call into my Mapbox code below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    var main = Map('map', {
        api: 'http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/test.map-j9pcd8xs.jsonp',

        center: {
            lat: 40.593000,      
            lon: -73.743126406355,      
            zoom: 10                   
        },
        zoomRange: [8, 15],             
        features: [                  
            'zoomwheel',
            'tooltips',
            'movetips',  
            'zoombox',
            'zoompan',
            'share'
        ]
    });

    main.layers({
        income: {api: 'http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/test.incomedec3.jsonp',
              center: {                   
                ease: 500               
            }                         
        },
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

> I have another tile of markers, but I would like to change this to Leaflet dataset and clustering.

That example is built using Modest Maps, you'll need to rewrite it to use Leaflet.